# Существуют ли переходники с gpio на usb, которые можно использовать в связки с "малинкой"?

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi, электроника, gpio

Существуют ли переходники с gpio на usb, которые можно использовать в связки с "малинкой"? Проблема в том, что у меня перестали работать usb порты на распбери пи, но сама плата работает и мне крайне не хочется покупать новую. К сожалению я не нашел такого в интернете

Comment: Если и существуют, то будут стоить минимум в половину малины, причем без всякой гарантии работы.

Comment: Можно GPIO из USB получить, а вот обратное -- задача на дипломный проект какого-нибудь российского ВУЗа.